# links in buttons within html email doent redirect

Tags: html, email

The links in my email buttons don't redirect the user when they are clicked on, even a simple redirect as shown in the code snippet below has no effect when clicked.(tested in hotmail, gmail, yahoo mail so far). Any suggestions?

```
 <p >
       If you feel your email account has been compromised please take the appropriate steps to secure your account.<br />
       Please click the button below so we can remove this registration request.<br />
           <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="240 " height="36" bgcolor="#0478db" style="margin-left:15px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color :ghostwhite !important; display: block;">
                        <a href="http:\\www.google.com"  style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
                        Delete Registration Request
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
  </p>
```

When clicked on in gmail it takes me to a blank page; about:blank. In hotmail and Yahoo nothing happens

Comment: you should use slash instead of backslash in the href attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url syntax you have used is wrong

Urls are supposed to be like `http://www.google.com` not like `http:\\www.google.com`

Comment: Dumb mistake on the sample, I'll see if it works now in the built up real Url

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the URL as below

```
<p >
       If you feel your email account has been compromised please take the appropriate steps to secure your account.<br />
       Please click the button below so we can remove this registration request.<br />
           <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="240 " height="36" bgcolor="#0478db" style="margin-left:15px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color :ghostwhite !important; display: block;">
                        <a href="http://www.google.com"  style="color: #ffffff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
                        Delete Registration Request
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
  </p>
```